# When I run `react-scripts start` I get an eslint error. But when I run eslint by itself, I get no error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, create-react-app, react-scripts

I was working on a working branch.

Then I switched branches because I needed to work on my master branch.

There was a difference in node_modules between the working branch and the master branch, so I ran `yarn install` and then `yarn start`, but I got `Failed to compile` in the console. The error message was for ESLint.

```
Failed to compile.
src/routes/Viewer/useTemplateData.tsx
  Line 6:32: Missing file extension for ". /... /components/useRollbarFunction" import/extensions
  Line 6:32: Unable to resolve path to module '. /... /components/useRollbarFunction' import/no-unresolved
  Line 12:9: Unsafe assignment of an `any` value @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
  Line 12:37: Unsafe call of an `any` typed value @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
  Line 29:7: Unsafe member access .configure on an `any` value @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
  Line 29:7: Unsafe call of an `any` typed value @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
  Line 29:27: Unsafe assignment of an `any` value @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment
  Line 30:25: Unsafe member access .error on an `any` value @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access
  Line 30:25: Unsafe call of an `any` typed value @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call
```

However, when I ran `yarn eslint`, I did not get any errors in that area (I think this is the correct behavior).

I then removed node_modules, ran `yarn install` again, and then ran `yarn start` and the error was no longer there, but I could not figure out why the above behavior was happening.

Is this a special case? Or is there some difference between the eslint executed at `react-scripts start` and simply running `yarn eslint`?

---

Not sure if this will help, but the .eslintrc.js and the other configuration files are as follows

`.eslintrc.js`

```js
const { readGitignoreFiles } = require("eslint-gitignore");
const gitignore = readGitignoreFiles({ cwd: __dirname });
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  ignorePatterns: [...gitignore, ".*lintrc.js"],
  env: { es2020: true, browser: true, jest: true },
  parser: "babel-eslint",
  extends: ["airbnb", "airbnb/hooks", "plugin:import/recommended", "plugin:import/typescript", "prettier"],
  rules: {
    "no-alert": "off",
    "no-console": ["warn", { allow: ["error"] }],
    "no-unused-vars": ["warn"],
    "no-plusplus": ["error", { allowForLoopAfterthoughts: true }],
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": ["off"],
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "padding-line-between-statements": ["error", { blankLine: "always", prev: "*", next: "return" }],
    "lines-between-class-members": ["error", "always", { exceptAfterSingleLine: true }],
    "import/extensions": ["error", "ignorePackages", { js: "never", jsx: "never", ts: "never", tsx: "never" }],
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": ["error", { extensions: [".jsx", ".tsx"] }],
    "react/jsx-uses-react": "off",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "react/jsx-key": ["error"],
    "no-underscore-dangle": ["error", { allow: ["_id"] }],
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": ["off"],
    camelcase: ["error", { properties: "always" }],
    "prefer-destructuring": ["error", { AssignmentExpression: { array: false } }],
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
      parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
      extends: [
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
        "prettier",
      ],
      parserOptions: { project: "./tsconfig.eslint.json", tsconfigRootDir: __dirname },
      rules: {
        "no-use-before-define": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-use-before-define": ["error"],
        "no-void": ["error", { allowAsStatement: true }],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

`tsconfig.eslint.json`

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Does the react-scripts invoke the eslint with any special flags? Do you from the command line?

Comment: The script named start in package.json contains `chmod +x . /env.sh && . /env.sh && mv config.js . /public/ && set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start`. env.sh seems to be a script to inject environment variables. This script is called at `yarn start`, but I don't think it has anything to do with eslint.

Comment: I switched the branch while the app was still up. that might be a cause, because I switched branch with the app off and tried the same thing and got no errors.